# Concerns related to neural network matlab toolbox

Tags: machine-learning, matlab, neural-networks

I have some concerns related to the use of `nntool` in MATLAB toolbox. Following links like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11807184/395857), I have found that `nntool` by default normalizes the inputs to the range `[-1 1]`. So I am a bit concerned, I created a neural network with `tansig` activation in the first layer and `logsig` activation in the output layer. I manually normalized the outputs to the range of `[0 1]` in the data and fed it to `nntool`.

Now my question is does `nntool` further normalizes it to the range `[-1 1]`. If it does then it is not correct, the output of `logsig` cannot be in the range of `[-1 1]`.

I am using the `newfit` function like this

```
load house_dataset;
net = newfit(houseInputs,houseTargets,20);
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

`nntool` has a large number of tunable parameters, refer to the [documentation](http://www.varpa.org/Docencia/Files/nnet.pdf) for more details. In particular section **Preprocessing and Postprocessing** deals with different types of pre- and postprocessing techniques which are available in the toolbox.

When you look at the **newfit** definition you can find such information:

> **Purpose** Create fitting network
>
> **Syntax** net = newfit(P,T,S,TF,BTF,BLF,PF,IPF,OPF,DDF)
>
> **Description** newfit(P,T,S,TF,BTF,BLF,PF,IPF,OPF,DDF) takes the following:
>
> (...)
>
> `IPF` Row cell array of input processing functions. Default is 
>   `{'fixunknowns','remconstantrows','mapminmax'}`.
>
> `OPF` Row cell array of output processing functions. Default is 
>   `{'remconstantrows','mapminmax'}`
>
> (...)

So you can simply change them to `IPF={'fixunknowns','remconstantrows'}` and `OPF={'remconstantrows'}` to turn the min-max mapping off.